# how do you compare int arrays with a boolean method?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, boolean, compare, static-methods

I'm trying to write a method that compared two arrays.

If the arrays have the same contents then return true; and if not, then return false. Can you please help me with the code?

```
public static boolean identicalArrays(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    if(a.length != b.length) return false;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)   
    {        
        if(a[i] != b[i]) i = a.length;
        else return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: why do you want to have this line `if(a[i] != b[i]) i = a.length;`

Comment: Why not use a built in comparison function?

Comment: TimeString -- If two pieces are not equal then set i equal to a value that will take you out of the loop.